# Error while uploading file via CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, fine-uploader

While uploading a file via CloudFront to AWS S3 bucket I receive the following error

The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

The same upload, but directly to S3 works. I am using react-fine-uploader and JAVA backend. I can see that V4 is being used in the backend. What could be the reason?
In the java backend I have:

```
 if (req.getQueryString() != null && req.getQueryString().contains("v4=true")) {
            System.out.println("Signing with the V4 signature");
            handleV4SignatureRequest(jsonObject, contentJson, req, resp);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Signing with the V2 signature");
            handleV2SignatureRequest(jsonObject, contentJson, req, resp);
        }
```

The SOP shows "Signing with the V4 signature"

My configuration:

```
 uploader = new FineUploaderS3({
    options: {
      debug: true,
      deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        endpoint: `${config.environment.api_baseUrl}/s3`,
        customHeaders: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(config.WS_USERNAME + ':' + config.WS_PASSWORD)
        }
      },
      request: {
        endpoint: `${config.AWS_S3_END_POINT}`,
        accessKey: `${config.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY}`
      },
      signature: {
        endpoint: `${config.environment.api_baseUrl}/s3/signature`,
        version: 4,
        customHeaders: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(config.WS_USERNAME + ':' + config.WS_PASSWORD),
        }
      },
      uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: `${config.environment.api_baseUrl}/s3/success`,
        customHeaders: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(config.WS_USERNAME + ':' + config.WS_PASSWORD)
        }
      },
      validation: {
        sizeLimit: 5000000,
        itemLimit: 10
      },
      callbacks: {
        onComplete: (id, fileName, responseJSON) => {
          const { submittedFiles } = this.state;
          let newFile = {
            name: responseJSON.name,
            s3Bucket: responseJSON.s3Bucket,
            s3Key: responseJSON.s3Key,
            size: this.uploader.methods.getSize(id),
            uuid: responseJSON.uuid
          }

          submittedFiles.push(newFile);
          this.setState({ submittedFiles });
        },
        onDeleteComplete: (id) => {
          const { submittedFiles } = this.state;
          let newUuid = this.uploader.methods.getUuid(id);
          let removeElement = arrayObjectIndexOf(submittedFiles, newUuid, 'uuid');

          submittedFiles.splice(removeElement, 1);
          this.setState({ submittedFiles });
        }
      },
      messages: {
        tooManyItemsError: 'You can only add 10 files'
      },
      chunking: {
        enabled: true
      },
      objectProperties: {
        region: `${config.AWS_S3_REGION}`
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: *"I can see that V4 is being used in the backend."*  Can you explain how you see that, and perhaps show us what the signed URL or Authorization header (not sure which you are using) looks like?

Comment: I have updated the question with the configuration file as well as JAVA code. When I say that I see v4 is used, I meant it recognizes "v4=true" is passed from client to the backend and uses handleV4SignatureRequest method to sign.

Comment: I wonder why the same code works when I upload directly to S3. Is there any additional configurations are needed for CF?

Comment: Possibly... but it's hard to say exactly what the issue might be without seeing the request that is actually being sent.  If you are using a CloudFront Origin Access Identity, things get more complex because CloudFront tries to re-sign the request, itself, using the OAI. Are you?  If you aren't adding an `x-amz-content-sha256` header containing the payload hash, that would be problematic, but I think that is required when uploading directly to S3, so that *should* already be present.  Is it?

Comment: Based on successful direct upload to S3, I would assume that all the headers are present. Origin access identity is set to "Use an Existing Identity"

Comment: I would like to try to upload using some other tools, java or maybe some AWS client. Any pointers on how to setup such a test case?

Comment: I created new S3 bucket which supports V2 signature and it works, so there is some issue in the link CF-S3 when V4 is required.

Comment: Was this a `PUT` or `POST`?  I just remembered solving this once before, for `POST` uploads.  With `POST`, you can't have the origin access identity active on the root `/`page of the bucket.  You have to create a second origin pointing to the same bucket without the OAI, and you have to create a separate Cache Behavior for `/` that uses that origin. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=798813&#799099